# Lines in a file is not displayed (python)

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner. So I encountered this problem. The file has 100 songs, each song with an id(X), title(T), time sig(M) and key sig(K),
the format of the text file is the same throughout the file. 
However it skipped 8 lines. Some of the tunes in the file has several titles, but only one is to be displayed

```
file = open("musicFile.abc", "r")
idNum = ""
title = ""
timesig = ""
keysig = ""
total = 0
for line in file:
    if line[0] == 'X':
        idNum = line[2:]
    elif line[0] == 'T':
        sep = ','  
        line = line.split(sep, 1)[0]   
        title = line[2:]
        for i in range(4):
            if next(file) == 'T': 
            break
    elif line[0] == 'M':
        timesig = line[2:]
    elif line[0] == 'K':
        keysig = line[2:]
        fullLine = "Id: " + idNum + " .... " + "Title: " + title + " .... " + \
        "Time sig: " + timesig + " .... " + "Key sig: " + keysig
    fullLine = fullLine.replace("\n", "") 
    print(fullLine)
    total += 1

print("\n-------------------------------")
print("There are ", total, "tunes in the file")
print("-------------------------------")
```

This is the compiled result:
[compiled program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AEJp.png)

It should display there are 100 tunes in the file.

Comment: Please include the result of the program in the post itself.

Comment: show `"musicFile.abc"` we will count it manually.

Comment: A good tip for Stack Overflow but also just for debugging your own programs: try to make the problem smaller. Currently, your problem involves  nearly 30 lines of code and hundreds of lines of data. That's a lot of places to look. You can narrow down the data by simply copying *half* your data into a new file. If the problem still happens with the smaller file, you now have a smaller number of places to look for the problem. Likewise, you can copy your code to a new file but remove some of the logic (perhaps one branch of an if/elif/elif). Keep shrinking: a smaller problem is easier to solve!

Comment: @RJHunter ,noted ! ill keep that in mind

Comment: In your case, I think you should be able to trim down the problem to about 10 lines of code and just two or three songs. Once it's that size, the problem will be obvious (either obvious to you or obvious to someone here).

Answer (score 0):

You use `next(file)` which reads next line so you skip some lines.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, some tunes in the file has more than 1 titles. But only one title is to be displayed